# Database is locked in SQLite [Java]

Tags: java, database, sqlite

**updated**

```
try
        {
            sqlite.setDbPath(dbPath);
            con = sqlite.connect();
            if(!con.isClosed()) 
            {
                String query="SELECT Username,Password FROM Apps WHERE Username ='"+username+"'"; // and Password='"+password+"'";
                ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
                while(rs.next())
                {
                        if(rs.getString("Username").equals(username))//confronto se Username è gia esistente
                        {
                            trovato = true;
                            risultato = "gia' presente";
                        }
                }

                if(trovato==false) {
                    createUsers(username,password,name,surname,email,appname,ip,authorized,token);
                    risultato="inserito";
                }

                if(con!=null)
                {
                    con.close();
                }
                if(sqlite != null)
                {
                    sqlite.close();
                }
                if(rs != null)
                {
                    rs.close();
                }
            }
```

In try catch block I've open connection with database embedded but in first time i don't close all connection.. 
With if control the program close all open connection and works well

Comment: Do you have your database opened in some sql editor? That'll probably cause an error like that.

Comment: I try to close sqleditor but i've the same problem

Comment: IIRC SQLite only allows a single connection to the database, so if you have multiple connections it will fail. This may be a limitation of older versions though, so in that case you may need to upgrade the sqlite version you're using. That said, in my opinion, SQLite is not really a suitable database for a web application.

Comment: Your current code has a lot of potential resource leaks. I'd suggest that you rewrite your code to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), it will simplify things a lot and reduce the complexity of your code.

Comment: BTW: `con.createStatement().close();` makes zero sense. You don't need to create a statement if you're going to immediately close it.

Comment: I update the code but it doesn't work

Comment: You're still not using try-with-resources.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's ok now?

Comment: Please read the link about try-with-resources. You are still not using it.

Comment: I have update my answer with a try-with-resource version

Comment: I update the code, it is ok?

Comment: Remove the outer `try{} catch{}`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok, done

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: `if(trovato==false)
                {
                    String query1="INSERT INTO Apps (Username,Password,Name,Surname,Email,AppName,Ip,Authorized,Token) VALUES ('" + username + "'," + "'" +password +"','" + name + "','" + surname + "','" +email + "','" + appname + "','"+ip+"','"+authorized+"','"+token+"')";
                    System.out.println(query1);
                    //con.createStatement().execute(query1);
                    con.createStatement().executeUpdate(query1);                        
                    System.out.println("inserito");
                }`

Comment: In my opinion i make error in this part of code... because first if condition the code works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

Here is an abbreviated version using try-with-resource instead. Code is simpler and shorter

```
public String RegisterUser(... ) {
    boolean trovato = false;
    int authorized=0;

    SqliteConnection sqlite = new SqliteConnection();
    String dbPath="C:/Users/l.pellegrini/eclipse-workspace/ClayAPI_dbembedded/claydb.db";
    String query="SELECT Username,Password FROM Apps WHERE Username ='"+username+"' and Password='"+password+"'";

    try (java.sql.Connection con = sqlite.connect();
         Statement statement = con.createStatement();
         Statement updStatement = con.createStatement();
         ) {
        ResultSet rsActiveServices = con.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        // handle result set as before
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("errore" + e);
    }
    if(trovato==false) {
        createUser(username, password, name, surname, appname, email, ip)
    }
    return "username: " + username;
}


private createUser(String username, String password, String name, String surname, String appname, String email, String ip {
    String query1="INSERT INTO Apps (Username,Password,Name,Surname,Email,AppName,Ip,Authorized,Token) VALUES ('" + username + "'," + "'" +password +"','" + name + "','" + surname + "','" +email + "','" + appname + "','"+ip+"','"+authorized+"','"+token+"')";         
    SqliteConnection sqlite = new SqliteConnection();
    String dbPath="C:/Users/l.pellegrini/eclipse-workspace/ClayAPI_dbembedded/claydb.db";

    try (java.sql.Connection con = sqlite.connect();
         Statement statement = con.createStatement();) {
        updStatement.executeUpdate(query1);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("errore" + e);
    }
}
```

---

It could very well be that your prepared statement isn't properly closed. Change

```
ResultSet rsActiveServices = con.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

to

```
statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rsActiveServices = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

where statement is declared before `try`

```
java.sql.Connection con = null;
Statement statement = null;
```

and then close it in your `finally` clause

```
finally
{
    try
    {
        statement.close();
        con.close();
        sqlite.close();
    }
```

**Update 1**

I just noticed that your are trying to close your objects twice which is wrong, remove the first set of `close` calls and only close within `finally {}` at the end.

Comment: `finally
{
    try
    {
        statement.close();
        con.close();
        sqlite.close();
    }`    i can't put statement.close(); into finally

Comment: @lucapellegrini, simple mistake by me. You need to declare the variable outside the  `try` clause. I'll update the answer

Comment: Using try-with-resources is probably better (and shorter).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know but this felt like the simplest way to move forward.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel link me the page

Comment: @lucapellegrini I have updated my answer by adding a try-with-resource version

Comment: You make the appropriate changes yes, at the top and at the end.

Comment: @lucapellegrini try moving the creation of the second statement to the same place as the others (I'll update my answer) or even better move it to another method (together with all other try-with-resource code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok i try

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I update the code but it doesn't function... console show the same error

Comment: @lucapellegrini move the update to a separate method and call it at the end of the current method if `trovato` is false

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i don't understand.. make an example please

Comment: @lucapellegrini I have made an example. Note that this is written directly here so it is not compiled or syntax checked.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

I do errors with open and close connection in Main.. With SQLite the connection you have to open and close everytime it's carried out a query of all type(Insert, Delete,Update ecc..)